# How do I get my (lost) device's serial number from its UDID?

Tags: ipad, serial-number, udid

I lost an iPad, and I need the serial number - all I have of it is the UDID.

The device is not registered, I don't have the box, and I don't have backups of it either.

I suppose that calling Apple could get me the serial number if I provide the UDID. But that's a step I'd like to avoid. Perhaps there is an email address? (Have lurked their site but I've been unable to find such).

For context, this question comes from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90459/identifying-a-lost-stolen-ipad-without-connecting-it-to-a-computer-or-downloadin?noredirect=1#comment106184_90459 - from the comments it seems like getting the serial number would be the most appropiate way to identify my lost iPad, since I have certain complications using the UDID to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one way.

I am an iOS developer, and I once used this iPad for development. Xcode has an **Organizer** window, which keeps tracks of the devices I used for development. The iPad appears on the list, and it also displays the serial number.

This of course only works if you have developed with the device using Xcode. I wonder if there is a more standard way to get the serial number.